# Prove that a function is not holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Prove that the function $(Im z)^2$ is not holomorphic is any open subset of $C$.

Please help!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations

Comment: What are your ideas?

Comment: If $f=\Im(z)^2$, then $u(x,y)=y^2$ and $v(x,y)=0$. Now calculate the CR-DGLs as mentioned in the first commend.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z=x+iy$ then $(\Im z)^2=y^2=u+iv.$ Since every holomorphic function satisfies Cauchy-Riemann equations i.e. $\partial u/\partial x=\partial v/\partial y.$ Here $\partial u/\partial x=0$  and $\partial v/\partial y=2y.$ This implies $(\Im z)^2$ is differentiable only at $0,$ that is there does not exist any open set where $(\Im z)^2$ is differentiable.